# Oracle stored procedure multiple resultsets

Tags: asp.net, oracle, gridview

I have one oracle stored proc that will select customers based on a condition and also select all orders for customers that fulfill the requirements of the first select.

I have tried code like:

```
OPEN customer_cur FOR
SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE Country = 'UK';

OPEN orders_cur FOR
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE CustomreNo in (select CustomerNo from customer_cur);
```

This doesn't work as you can't select from a cursor but I need a means to implement the desired behavior.

I want to return two table so that I can display a hierarchical grid to the user.

Thanks
Alan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OPEN customer_cur FOR
SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE Country = 'UK';

OPEN orders_cur FOR
SELECT * FROM Orders, Customer
WHERE Orders.CustomreNo=Customer.CustomerNo
and Customer.Country = 'UK';
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, I'd over simplified this question but you let me see the answer, I just duplicated some of the inner joins from the first select into the second and job done. :) Thanks for your help